# How to run clojure on Mac OS X?

Tags: clojure

I'm following the examples from the book 'Programming Clojure', and I'm at page 
17 to run (require 'example.introduction).

I have set clojure at ~/bin/clojure as follows

```
java -server \
     -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8888 -cp ... clojure.lang.Repl
```

The -cp contains . (current directory). When I try it with clojure, I get the following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at clojure.lang.Repl.(Repl.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.MultiFn.(Ljava/lang/String;Lclojure/lang/IFn;Ljava/lang/Object;Lclojure/lang/IRef;)V (utils.clj:0)
        at clojure.lang.RT.(RT.java:290)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.MultiFn.(Ljava/lang/String;Lclojure/lang/IFn;Ljava/lang/Object;Lclojure/lang/IRef;)V (utils.clj:0)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:4153)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:4470)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:327)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:316)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:406)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:376)
        at clojure.core$load__4557$fn__4559.invoke(core.clj:3427)
        at clojure.core$load__4557.doInvoke(core.clj:3426)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:413)
        at clojure.core$load_one__4520.invoke(core.clj:3271)
...
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:327)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:312)
        at clojure.lang.RT.maybeLoadResourceScript(RT.java:308)
        at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:430)
        at clojure.lang.RT.(RT.java:286)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.MultiFn.(Ljava/lang/String;Lclojure/lang/IFn;Ljava/lang/Object;Lclojure/lang/IRef;)V
        at clojure.contrib.duck_streams__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.contrib.duck_streams__init.(Unknown Source)
...
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:4142)
        ... 28 more
```

I tried to run clojure as follows.

```
alias clojure='java -jar $JARDIR/clojure.jar '
```

But it doesn't have the CLASSPATH that I setup in .bashrc correctly, when I run [the command](http://pupeno.com/blog/printing-the-class-path-in-clojure/) as follows.

```
(println (seq (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))))
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: For all but the most trivial experimentation, it's best to get used to [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org).  I learned that the hard way when I started out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Stuart Halloway's code that accompanies the book:

1. Clone Stu's code from GitHub: `$ git clone http://github.com/stuarthalloway/programming-clojure.git`
2. `cd` into the `programming-clojure` directory that was created: `$ cd programming-clojure`
3. Run the `repl.sh` script in the `bin/` directory: `$ ./bin/repl.sh` (make sure you run it from the repo root, not the `bin/` directory, otherwise it won't work).

The script will set up all the necessary paths, including the paths to the examples in the book.

(You can do it manually, of course, but at any rate, you have to download or clone the `programming-clojure` source code anyway for the examples to work.)